# How to get data from an array inside session in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

i want to get data from an array inside of session. i want to get the name of each array. 
But when i print $x and $y like in the code below, it doesn't print anything

THE ANSWER BEFORE IS CORRECT BUT HOW ABOUT THIS

```
$this->session->userdata['namearray'];
```

this is print_r of the session

```
Array (
        [0] => stdClass Object
        (

                     [name] =>a

          )

         [1] => stdClass Object
        (

                     [name] =>b


             )

    )

foreach ($this->session->userdata['namearray'] as $x=>$y){
    print_r("this is x".$x);
    print_r("this is y".$y);
}
```

Comment: what is $this->session->userdata?

Comment: $this->session->set_userdata is how to set the session in controller of codeigniter
$this->session->userdata is how to get the data that set before @GiacomoM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've written a possible solution for your query, comments are mentioned wherever necessary. See if it helps you.

```
$nameArray = $this->session->userdata('namearray'); // access the session data like this (remove namearray with your session name)

foreach ($nameArray as $x){ // traverse the data
   echo "this is x ".$x->name;  // use -> to access objects
}
```

Comment: how about this case bro @sauhardnc

Comment: Hey @Loka! If you accept an answer, you shouldn't change the question because now my answer doesn't answer your changed question. So, anyone who might run into a similar problem, will not find this answer useful which is the purpose of StackOverlfow. If you must edit **if you must** write Edit and below it share the new issue, you're facing but don't delete the previous one. **Please** correct the  question like this. And then I'll try to answer your new problem, ok? :)