# How to get data from an array in array inside session in codeigniter?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, object, session

I want to get data from an array in array inside of session. i want to get the `rule1` of each array. But when i print `$y` like in the code below, it doesn't print anything

```
$this->session->userdata['namearray'];
```

this is `print_r` of the session

```
Array (
        [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [class] =>array (
                   [0] => stdClass Object
                   (
                     [rule1] =>a

                    )
                   [1] => stdClass Object
                   (
                     [rule1] =>b

                    )
             )
         [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [class] =>array (
                   [0] => stdClass Object
                   (
                     [rule1] =>c

                    )
                   [1] => stdClass Object
                   (
                     [rule1] =>d

                    )
             )

    )

foreach ($nameArray as $y){ 
                $string2[] = $y->class->rule1;  
             }
```

how to make the correct foreach

Comment: Please revert your previous question to original.  _/\\_

Comment: done @sauhardnc

Comment: Does this answer your question? [codeigniter pass array in session and retrieve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17446906/codeigniter-pass-array-in-session-and-retrieve)

Answer (score 0):

I've written a possible solution for your query, which is quite similar to your previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61888505/how-to-get-data-from-an-array-inside-session-in-codeigniter/61888756). Comments are mentioned wherever necessary. See if it helps you.

```
$nameArray = $this->session->userdata('namearray'); // access the session data like this (remove namearray with your session name)

foreach ($nameArray as $x){ // traverse the data

    foreach($x->class as $class){ // now traverse the class array which is an object of parent array

        $newArr[][] = $class->rule1;  // use -> to access objects

    }
}
```

This will return an array like

```
// print_r($newArr);

[0] => 
      [0] => a
      [1] => b
[1] => 
      [0] => c
      [1] => d
```

Comment: i want to make it into a two array  @sauhardnc
0  a b
1  c d

Comment: What do you mean by two array? Like first array will have a and b, and second will have c and d  Like so? @Loka

Comment: Can you share the desired output in the question?

Comment: inside the second foreach 
 $string2[]=$class->rule1;
 and then 
$data = array( 'rule' =>$string2 );
$this->load->view('view',$data)

Comment: because in the view i want to make  2 div and in every div there is the name. 

first div is a and b  and the second div is c and d